# How can I make all created directories assign to a subdomain?

Tags: domains, htaccess, subdomain

So we have a .php file that creates a directory that is named after user input from a form, and uses file_put_contents to have a n index.php already in that directory. Our problem is that it can be only accessed by website.com/domain instead of domain.website.com. How would I automatically assign a subdomain with the same name to the directory? We have tried just about everything the internet will give us, and have been stuck for 3 hrs. We are using Apache on Debian.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, you need to explain yourself more clearly, if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a subdomain using only PHP application.

First you need to configure apache virtual host to accept requests for multiple domains.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

With wildcard subdomain *.example.com, main domain will receive all requests for any sub-domain, which can be handled by either using .htaccess or with PHP application.

Now, use htaccess code to rewrite URL i.e. load subdirectory on subdomain URL,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdir.example.com
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir/%{REQUEST_URI}  -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

** need to write more generic htaccess code.